# Some Perspective on low level Imaging in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, image-processing

**Purpose of my Question:**
I am hoping to get some perspective that is not so easily gotten by reading Microsoft overviews, class and method descriptions. Hopefully those more experienced than I can point me in the right direction.

**Background of my Question:**
I am hardware engineer that develops silicon devices to process the output of CMOS image sensors to create a final picture. I usually prototype and test my algorithms in C or C++ (Yes super old school I know) before committing to hardware. On my latest project I decided to use c# and WPF instead.

**What I tried and am still stuck on:**
BUT I am finding that c# and WPF are not so image friendly. For example I can only find one class that lets me manipulate at the pixel level, or create a bitmap from an array - and at that a one dimensional array. Two dimensional arrays are classic and very intuitive for imaging work - would Microsoft really not have any pre-canned classes to convert from a 2D array to a bitmap??? I must be using the wrong classes (I have tried almost everything under System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource ).

Where have I gone wrong? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

WPF is not an imaging library or intended for image-processing, it is a UI platform/framework. `BitmapSource` is intended for displaying raster data in a WPF context, not for manipulating bitmap data.

You have a few options:

- `System.Drawing` - which is a .NET wrapper around GDI. You can access raw bitmap data using `bitmap.LockBits` and `unsafe` C# `byte*` and `UInt32*` pointers to manipulate the data.

  - GDI supported hardware acceleration of 2D drawing operations until Windows Vista. Windows 7 added some hardware acceleration back, but the majority of operations are still performed in software. Given that CPUs today are so fast this shouldn't be a problem in practice. If you really do need modern hardware-accelerated 2D drawing you should use Direct2D.
  - Note that `System.Drawing` is not available in .NET Core as it heavily tied to Windows' GDI.
- [AForge.NET](http://www.aforgenet.com/) - is an open-source image-processing, computer vision, and artificial-intelligence library, however it builds on-top of `System.Drawing`.
- [ImageProcessor](http://imageprocessor.org/) - is actually two libraries: the first is a wrapper around `System.Drawing` which provides common consumer-application image-processing tasks, such as generating thumbnails - the other is a .NET Core-capable image processing library which implements required bitmap operations itself: [ImageSharp](https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/ImageSharp).

Comment: Well I should be more clear. I don't need a library to make image manipulations, those are the algorithms I am supposed to be writing & given that I am designing for hardware the code is going to be totally different then what you would do for a PC application - so working with an image as an array is what I want to keep.

Comment: What I want to offload is stuff like "show the bitmap to the user" and ask the user to enter a value for noise that gets passed to the class emulating the sensor. I feel like WPF is great for that stuff. It's the getting array to be a bitmap and getting a bitmap to be an array (because I need a bitmap to make display easy in wpf) that's giving me trouble.

Answer (score 0):

See my Q&A here

[Creating a BitmapImage WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375943/creating-a-bitmapimage-wpf/5376929#5376929)

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);

IntPtr hBitmap = bitmap.GetHbitmap();
try
{
    imageSource = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(hBitmap,
                                                        IntPtr.Zero,
                                                        Int32Rect.Empty,
                                                        System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
}
catch (Exception e) { }
finally
{
    DeleteObject(hBitmap);
}
```

Comment: For what its worth I used this code for the exact same use case as you; displaying images from a cmos sensor :)